# Logic App using Custom Connector : Previous selected Value displayed in Drop Down in logic app Trigger

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created 2 drop-down lists in the logic app custom connector trigger and used them in Logic App. I have bound the second drop-down list using the value selected from the first drop-down list. For the first time, it works fine if I select any value from the first DDL. But, If I change the value again in the first DDL, the previously selected value (GUID) in the second DDL is displayed by default in the second DDL.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? I doubt this may the cache issue in the logic app, but no idea on resolving this.

Comment: Logic App custom connector - issue in drop-down list binding in trigger